# ATTiny85 Interrupts in Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, c, arduino, attiny

I have an ATTiny85 which I program using a sparkfun programmer (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11801) and the ATTiny Board Manager I am using is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damellis/attiny/ide-1.6.x-boards-manager/package_damellis_attiny_index.json

Below is my code, I am having trouble getting the interrupt to work when I ground Pin 2.
I have tested the LED does work outside of the interrupt (inside the loop). Any suggestions are welcome.

```
#include "Arduino.h"

#define interruptPin 2

const int led = 3;
bool lastState = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(interruptPin, pulseIsr, CHANGE);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

}


void pulseIsr() {
    if (!lastState) {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      lastState = 1;
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);  // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      lastState = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was way off.

Here is how to set up an interrupt on the ATTiny85 using the Arduino IDE (this example uses digital pin 4 (pin 3 on the chip):

```
#include "Arduino.h"

const byte interruptPin = 4;
const byte led = 3;
bool lastState = false;

ISR (PCINT0_vect) // this is the Interrupt Service Routine
{
  if (!lastState) {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    lastState = true;
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);  // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    lastState = false;
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // set to input with an internal pullup resistor (HIGH when switch is open)
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  // interrupts
  PCMSK  |= bit (PCINT4);  // want pin D4 / pin 3
  GIFR   |= bit (PCIF);    // clear any outstanding interrupts
  GIMSK  |= bit (PCIE);    // enable pin change interrupts 
}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one possible error with your Boolean data type. Boolean data types are either true or false. I see that your using it for variable lastState. The initialization to equal 0 is something that I don't think the compiler allows. Maybe you should try setting the bool variable to the following...

```
bool lastState = true;

if (!lastState) {
// what you want your code to perform if lastState is FALSE
}
else {
//what else you want your code to perform if lastState is TRUE
}
```

OR

```
bool lastState = true;

if (lastState) {
// what you want your code to perform if lastState is TRUE
}
else {
//what else you want your code to perform if lastState is FALSE
}
```

Here is a helpful pdf on Boolean data types, available for download through my Nextcloud instance.

https://nextcloud.point2this.com/index.php/s/so3C7CzzoX3nkzQ

I know this doesn't fully fix your problem, but hopefully this will help some.